# Load items from file and split them into array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have to do a program in C# Form, which has to load from a file an ID number and a ADN formed by 20 letters, whatever the output has to be something like that:

//Edit: I'll try to explain it better; it's a C# Form program which has to load 20 people from a town(file) with their ADN, ID number and Name, after that i have to load from a file a single ADN without name or id number (which is the murderer; the program is a CSI game, you have a town with 20 people, someone does a murder and i have to find him) and then i have to COMPARE the single ADN with all 20 ADNS and i have to find a % and then to find the murderer..

1;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A

2;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A

3;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A
...
The file has 20 lines.

I've tried this so far but.. it doesn't work

```
 using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;

    namespace CSI_Marconi_FORM
    {
        public partial class DNAabitanti : Form
        {
            public DNAabitanti()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void DNAabitanti_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"\\Repo\Studenti$\Informatica\SezCi\4Ci\Corneliu.Cotet\Documenti\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSI Marconi FORM\CSI Marconi FORM\bin\Debug\DNAabitanti.txt");
                reader = File.OpenText(@"\\Repo\Studenti$\Informatica\SezCi\4Ci\Corneliu.Cotet\Documenti\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSI Marconi FORM\CSI Marconi FORM\bin\Debug\DNAabitanti.txt");
                FormPrincipale.utenti = File.ReadAllLines(@"\\Repo\Studenti$\Informatica\SezCi\4Ci\Corneliu.Cotet\Documenti\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CSI Marconi FORM\CSI Marconi FORM\bin\Debug\DNAabitanti.txt").Length;
                string abitanti = reader.ReadToEnd();                          
                richTextBox1.Text = abitanti;                        
                reader.Close();
                FormPrincipale.database = new FormPrincipale.Persona[FormPrincipale.utenti];
                FormPrincipale.corrispondenze = new int [FormPrincipale.utenti];

                for (int i = 0; i < FormPrincipale.utenti; i++)
                {
                    string letto = "";
                    letto = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    string[] aus = letto.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                    FormPrincipale.database[i].dna = new string[20];

                    for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++)
                    {
                        if (j < 20)
                        {
                            FormPrincipale.database[i].dna[j] = aus[j];
                        }

                        if (j == 20)
                        {
                            FormPrincipale.database[i].nome = aus[j];
                        }

                        if (j == 21)
                        {
                            FormPrincipale.database[i].cognome = aus[j];
                        }

                    }              

                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So show us what you tried (and be much clearer about input and output).

Comment: Huh? So use `File.ReadAllLines`.

Comment: Thanks for your code. What does `FormPrincipale.utenti` evaluate too when you debug the code?

Comment: The `letto` string will always be empty. General solution: use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

You have to first replace all ';'s with space and then maek the individual change with ':' after the first digit.That will replace the whole string in correct format.

```
string line;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"d:\\textFile.txt");

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string output = "";
    //replacing all ';' with space
    output = line.Replace(";", " ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(output);
    //replacing character after number with ':'
    sb[1] = ':';
    output = sb.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(output);
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: It should work.The textFile.txt contains 20 Lines and this code retrieved each line and split those accordingly by the ';' sign. You better try it.

Comment: I copy/paste the same code, the out is: 1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: I have to spit the letters.. because after i have to compare them with another ADN so..

Comment: Updated the answer. Now it's giving the output in the format you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, try something like:

```
var myArray = myFileContents.Split(new char [] { '\n' });
```

Comment: or this one: `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filePath");`